# How do you use sklearn StandardScaler on a pandas dataFrame without scaling the names of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statsmodels, scaling

I believe that I am scaling the column names in the dataFrame and that is why there are errors. How do I prevent this? I notice that the names of my columns in the dataFrame were changed from 'Inflation', 'Homes' to 0 and 1, maybe because I am scaling the column names. Then I change the array back to a dataFrame because the standard scalar turned my original dataFrame into a numpy array. I need it as a dataFrame to perform a regression with sklearn. Thanks:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_excel("C:/Users/ME/OneDrive/Desktop/simple regress.xlsx")
print(df)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

num_features = ['Inflation', 'Homes']
X = df[num_features]
std_scaler = StandardScaler() 
df_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(X)

df_scaled

# convert the array back to a dataframe
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(df_scaled)


    0               1
0   -1.021149   -0.219107
1   -1.006189   -0.248034
2   -1.216238   -0.326069
3   -1.195059   -0.403671
4   -1.181612   -0.419835

   
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
#Next use the ols function to create a regression model using that data in 
#the dataframe #called df  and fit the data of the dataframe into the model

result = smf.ols(formula='1 ~ 0', data=df).fit()
```

I get

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21632\2193012581.py in <module>
      2 #Next use the ols function to create a regression model using that data in
      3 #the dataframe #called df  and fit the data of the dataframe into the model
----> 4 result = smf.ols(formula='1 ~ 0', data=df).fit()
      5 
      6 # Print the parameters/coefficients in the regression equation

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, drop_cols, *args, **kwargs)
    224                        'formula': formula,  # attach formula for unpckling
    225                        'design_info': design_info})
--> 226         mod = cls(endog, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    227         mod.formula = formula
    228         # since we got a dataframe, attach the original

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    905             warnings.warn(msg, ValueWarning)
    906         super(OLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
--> 907                                   hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    908         if "weights" in self._init_keys:
    909             self._init_keys.remove("weights")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, weights, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    732             weights = weights.squeeze()
    733         super(WLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
--> 734                                   weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    735         nobs = self.exog.shape[0]
    736         weights = self.weights

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    188     """
    189     def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
--> 190         super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    191         self._data_attr.extend(['pinv_wexog', 'wendog', 'wexog', 'weights'])
    192 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    265 
    266     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
--> 267         super().__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    268         self.initialize()
    269 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
     91         hasconst = kwargs.pop('hasconst', None)
     92         self.data = self._handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst,
---> 93                                       **kwargs)
     94         self.k_constant = self.data.k_constant
     95         self.exog = self.data.exog

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    130 
    131     def _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs):
--> 132         data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    133         # kwargs arrays could have changed, easier to just attach here
    134         for key in kwargs:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    699     klass = handle_data_class_factory(endog, exog)
    700     return klass(endog, exog=exog, missing=missing, hasconst=hasconst,
--> 701                  **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
     86         self.const_idx = None
     87         self.k_constant = 0
---> 88         self._handle_constant(hasconst)
     89         self._check_integrity()
     90         self._cache = {}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in _handle_constant(self, hasconst)
    176                             (np.ones(self.exog.shape[0]), self.exog))
    177                 rank_augm = np.linalg.matrix_rank(augmented_exog)
--> 178                 rank_orig = np.linalg.matrix_rank(self.exog)
    179                 self.k_constant = int(rank_orig == rank_augm)
    180                 self.const_idx = None

<__array_function__ internals> in matrix_rank(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in matrix_rank(M, tol, hermitian)
   1901     S = svd(M, compute_uv=False, hermitian=hermitian)
   1902     if tol is None:
-> 1903         tol = S.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True) * max(M.shape[-2:]) * finfo(S.dtype).eps
   1904     else:
   1905         tol = asarray(tol)[..., newaxis]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     38 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     39           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 40     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     41 
     42 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

Comment: `formula='1 ~ 0'` : 0 and 1 are not valid python names and have special meaning in formulas. Using patsy's quote, e.g. `Q("not valid python name")` might work, but I don't know whether it works for integer column names.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest version of scikit-learn you can set the output type. It would look like this:

```py
    X = df[num_features]
    std_scaler = StandardScaler()
    std_scaler.set_output(transform='pandas')
    df_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

The `df_scaled` will be a pandas dataframe and the column names will be the same too i.e. "Inflation" and "Homes". You can read more about this in the [set_ouput API here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-set-output-py).